# Bug in matplotlib scatter plot script

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have run into a very strange issue (maybe a bug?) using matplotlib.  Long story short, if I run the script for a case that includes 4 datapoints, the color scheme is entirely messed up (I call for grayscale, but the points end up in default blue in the legend, and something else entirely on the plot).  However any other number of points seems to show up in grayscale as desired.  In the minimal case below, if the line:

```
plt.scatter([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], s= 40, c=colors[j], linewidth='0.5', marker=markers[j])
```

is altered to have the x, y points be [1,2,3,4] this problem arises, but if it is left unaltered the data shows up correctly in grayscale. Any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import operator

if __name__ == "__main__":

    savefile = 'P0p5_TINL.png'
    title = 'Normalized Extinction Residence Time\n Inlet Temperature = 300 K'
    xlabel = 'Inlet Temperature (K)'
    phi_list = [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
    numvals = len(phi_list)
    labels = ['$\phi$ = ', ' ']
    markers = ['o', 'v', 's', '+', 'p', 'D', '*']

    fig1 = plt.figure()    
    start = 0.0
    stop = 1.0
    col_list = np.linspace(start, stop, numvals)
    colors = [plt.cm.gray(x) for x in col_list]
    legend = []
    leg_list = []
    for j in range(0, len(phi_list)):
        plt.scatter([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], s= 40, c=colors[j], linewidth='0.5', marker=markers[j])
    for i in range(0, numvals):
        temp = [labels[0], str(phi_list[i]), labels[1]]
        leg_list = "".join(temp)
        legend.append(leg_list)

    # Axis definitions
    ax = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel, fontsize='14')
    ax.set_ylabel('Normalized Extinction Residence Time', fontsize='14')
    ax.set_xscale("linear")
    ax.set_yscale("linear")

    plt.legend(legend, bbox_to_anchor=(0.3, 0.95), fontsize='14')
    plt.title(title)    
    plt.show()
    fig1.savefig(savefile, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: This is going to sound weird but try using `color=colors[i]` instead of `c=colors[i]` for some reason I don't get the behaviour you mentioned by doing this. I think that maybe this is a bug and you should report it [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues)

Comment: I think you are right in that there is an issue here.  It may no be a bug per se, but pyplot is misinterpreting the color specification and the accepted workaround only works in this specific case by making sure that the length of the list does not correspond to the length of the data list.  If it so happens that you are plotting three values, the problem reoccurs.  With regards to your suggestion @pbreach the data points entirely disappear if I replace c with color.

Comment: I think it's because the last color is white (you're plotting the same data on top of each other 3 different times).

Comment: @ThemantheycallJayne This has nothing to do with the length of the data list, as pointed out in the edit to my answer. And matplotlib is not misinterpreting anything, it's more the user that ignores the documentation. Using a function outside its specification is not the function's fault.

Comment: With all due respect, there does not appear to be an alternative to using the colormap functionality in this way.  It may not be a bug, but it sure isn't a feature.  Blaming users for finding an edge case is obtuse in the extreme.

Comment: With all due respect, there are a couple of alternatives to providing a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence to the `c` argument. I've indicated some of them below. One should rather be happy about the fact that although the use of an RGB sequence is clearly discouraged, it still works for most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always helps to read [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter), where it says

> Note that `c` should not be a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence because that is indistinguishable from an array of values to be colormapped

When providing 4 points and supplying a tuple of 4 floats as `c` argument, pyplot will think that each float represents the color of the respective point and draws it using the default colormap.

Since the problem only occurs with exactly four points and since it is possible to specify colors as an RGB sequence with 3 values only, a workaround is to simply specify the 3-tuple, ommiting transparency.

```
plt.scatter([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], s= 40, c=colors[j][:-1], marker=markers[j])
```

If transparency is needed, one can set it using the `alpha` keyword.

---

*Edit:* 
To be more precise in the explanation: The issue has nothing to do with the length of the list supplied, but with the fact that the list can be interpreted as an array of values to be colormapped. 
Three conditions need to be satisfied for this to accur:

1. The supplied list has length 3 or 4
2. The supplied list is a list of float values.
3. The supplied list's length is identical to the number of points being drawn.

As soon as you break any of the above conditions, everything will work as expected. The above breaks condition 3. But of course you could also break condition 1 by specifying a single color

```
# use a predefined array like in the case of the markes
cols = ["#000000","#555555", "#aaaaaa","#ffffff"]
plt.scatter([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], s= 40, c=cols[j], marker=markers[j])

# or in dependence on the original col_list:
plt.scatter([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], s= 40, 
    c="#"+6*str(int(col_list[j]*9.9)), marker=markers[j])
```

And finally one could also break condition 2 by specifying a list of the same length, but with a color definition other than a float value:

```
plt.scatter([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4], s= 40, c=[colors[j]]*4, marker=markers[j])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This works for my specific case.

Comment: As a side note, this solution is not generalizable, in that if you happen to have a data set with three points you will have the same problem as before.  An alternative (but similar) approach is to simply replicate one of the data points in the data set so that there isn't a match in length between the color spec and the data (i.e. artificially creating the [1,2,3,4,5] case).

Comment: The problem occurs only in the case of 3 or 4 values. The above solution for a 4 point array is to specify color as a 3-tuple. The inverse is applicable as well. If you happen to have a 3 point array, you can specify color as RGBA using a 4-tuple.